# Magento Related Products Sidebar

Tags: magento

In Magento I took and duplicated a theme and made a few changes to the second one. Called it recipes, removed the price, etc. All worked out fine except! When I add a related product it shows up and says "other featured products". This is what the old theme said.

After some research i am seeing it is pulling this file from the "app/design/frontend/base/template/catalog/product/list folder instead of the theme folder ?

`http://www.colbrookkitchen.com/recipes/pico-de-gallo.html`

Answer (score 1):

Turn on template/path hints in your administration area:
System -> Config / Advanced -> Developer

This will show you exactly which template and block it belongs to. The product list template you are referring to just renders the products, it's possible the theme does not also include the header in that file.

Alternatively, a quick grep (or search via IDE if you are on Windows) for 'Other Featured Products' is a good solution, since that should be a fairly unique string.

Comment: That is what i did was search for "Other Featured Products" and it came up in the default folder, not the theme folder. I also changed the text in the default folder uploaded, and saw the change. But it will not pull the related.phtml from the theme folder that is being used. I assume it is a simple little fix I am just missing. Mark